# Ola Scripts installation in "Multi-server" Jobs Folder

Tags: ola-hallengren, central-management-server

I am installing the Ola scripts on a Central Management Server for multi-server administration. How can I get the jobs to show up under "Multi-server" Jobs Folder instead of the "Local Jobs" folder?

Answer (score 1):

The first part is to understand that a [Central Management Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/administer-multiple-servers-using-central-management-servers?view=sql-server-ver15) and a [Master Job Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-multiserver-environment?view=sql-server-ver15) are not the same. CMS is used to centrally manage instances, the master job server is used to deploy standardised jobs across mutiple servers. These two can be linked but are not directly related.

To have the jobs appear in Multi-Server Jobs, the jobs need to be configured as multi-server jobs. To do this, open the job and navigate to the Targets page. Select "Target Multiple Servers" and then select the target job servers to which you wish to deploy the job.

See [this link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2445/sql-server-multi-server-administration/) for more info.

If you're deploying Ola's maintenance jobs on a Master Job Server, there are several considerations you should make before deploying:

- All jobs have the same configuration, so your output file path must be accessible or identical on all servers. If it varies, you will get errors on the servers that don't match. NOTE: in later versions (2014+) of SQL, you can use the [Agent macro SQLLOGDIR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/use-tokens-in-job-steps?view=sql-server-ver15) to use a local path for output log files that vary between servers in a master job server.
- Backup jobs must be configured to backup to an identical path, either a local path that exists on all servers or a shared path that all servers can access.
- Exclusions for databases, tables etc must be applied to all servers, as the jobs cannot be individually modified on servers.
- Schedules are identical across servers, so if you're backing up to a shared location, you may encounter performance issues due to increased write activity at the same time.